# Excel Highlight one row based on another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I am trying to compare one row with another: IF the cells in Row 1 is equal to Row 2, THEN I must have  highlighting. I've tried 100 methods for over an hour now. The problem is that Excel keeps the formula the same across the row!! the formula needs to change, meaning: I am NOT trying to highlight the whole row based on just the first cell, the cell needs to dynamically change. First cell to first cell, 2nd to 2nd, etc. [image]

The circled words need to be highlighted.

---

Sorry to ensure everyone is clear on the requirement, here is my requirement: 
[image]
The solution, as a brilliant guy below mentioned, was a stupid $ sign.

Comment: Consider flagging for migration to http://superuser.com/.

Comment: ah this makes it more confusing because in the first picture row 10 is to be highlighted, but in the last picture it's row 9.

Comment: @Slai whether row 9/10 needs to change, the question/challenge remains the same: $ sign won't move with the moving fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the Formula to `= A10 = A9` (or just remove the $'s in yours) and Applies To `=$A$10:$E$10`

Comment: Brilliant.. I tried moving the dollar sign, removing one keeping another one.. adding one.. never thought of removing it all together. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want the circled words to be highlighted, the "Applies To" field should be "=$A$10,$E$10" - to see what rules are being applied in those cells, they need to be part of the current selection or you need to change the selection in "Show Formatting Rules For" to "This Worksheet."

If you want the comparison to not be absolute, remove the dollar signs.

Also consider adding [TRIM()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-trim-function) around A9 and A10 in the formula if you don't want stray spaces to lead to a detection of a difference.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @pnuts How would it not be? OP has to remove two dollar signs in the formula field and change two 9s to 10s in the Applies To field, to produce the desired behavior.  What do you think OP is after instead?

Comment: You can also set up the relative comparisons for just one cell (e.g. Applies to $A$10) and then use the Format Painter to copy that formatting, which includes the relative formula that will update automatically, to a whole bunch of other cells.

Comment: This was correct, the issue, the silly silly issue turned out to be the "$". The inappropriate placement of the $ sign caused the entire headache that lasted 1+ hour. Thank you so much. no idea who voted your answer Down. I voted it up